# Which is the logic we can know everything about?

Tags: logic

Given a logic and an associated language, then if all sentences which can be formulated in that language are enumerable, this seems to imply that all possible finitely axiomatizable theories (stated by collections of axioms) formulated in this language are enumerable as well.

Which is the strongest studied logic (with a bunch of basic truths, such as $A\lor \neg A$, i.e. a framework generally perceived as being a "logic") for which we can list all (finite, in the above sense) theories and so that these are also all decidable?

Comment: I assume you know of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem? There is no logic system in which **all** statements are provable. As for which is strongest, I would say it depends on what you want to prove as to which axioms you set.

Comment: @shade4159: There sure are logical system for which all (true) statements are provable. And I don't want to set any non-logical axioms, I want to consider all collections of axioms over a theory. What axioms are logical and which not is maybe debatable, that's why I formulated the question as I did. So I restrict myself to the conventionally studied logic and regarding strength, I want to adjoin the conventional axioms as long as it doesn't mean decidability is lost.

Comment: All sentences of any system are always enumerable. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri: Thanks for the response. It answers that I can list the theories and start sub-listing the theorems as well. But then I don't know the key points where decidability is lost.